# Xcode 7.2 doesn't take ad hoc provisioning profile when exporting an archive

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile, ad-hoc-distribution

When I try to save a build of my iOS app for ad hoc deployment in `Xcode` 7.2, `Xcode` takes a provisioning profile it generates (`XC Ad Hoc: *`), though I've set an ad hoc provisioning profile for this app that I created myself in Apple Member Center.

I tried the same with a previous version of `Xcode` (7.0.1), and it does take my ad hoc provisioning profile when exporting the archive.

Is someone else experiencing this?

Comment: just i have tested it is working fine.

Comment: I have just discovered that over-the-air install fails since upgrading to Xcode 7.2.  Same .ipa installed directly with Xcode works.

Comment: Fixed my problem by outputting new manifest.plist and including icons it wanted.  I was using an old .plist that did not include icon references, which is apparently necessary now.